# node и npm отказано в доступе

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробывал уже много способ:

1. Сменить терменал с повер шелл на cmd
2. Переустановить ноду по новой
   Может что-то конечно не так сделал, если есть идеи как исправить, поделитесь пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Такое ощущение, что блокировка идет на уровне ОС. И папка у вас странная(похоже что с ограничением прав на запуск).

Comment: В cmd пробывал тоже такая же ошибка